# Pine script ignores historical data in low time frame

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Pine script ignores historical data in low time frame.

This code is included in the strategy I added below.

```
var trend = input.int(1, title="Start trend (1 Long, -1 Short)", maxval = 1, minval = -1, group='//////////Main Trend // ////////')
if longCondition_2
     trend := 1
else if shortCondition_2
     trend := -1
```

The strategy determines the conditions of new positions according to the trend direction in the code above. However, when I run this strategy on the 1-second chart, it ignores the trend condition. Can you help me on this matter?